# utility function with useCallback

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, usecallback

I have a simple function with a useCallback in three part of my app to set an image:

```
const myLittleFunction = useCallback((image: string | undefined) => {
    mySetState(image)
  }, [
    mySetState,
  ])
```

this function is used to retrieve an image of a child component:

```
<MyChildComponent
  setImage={setPickerResponse}
  />
```

But since I have 3 times the same one in three different places, how could I make it a single utility function?

Comment: What do you mean by "3 time the same one"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to move the `STATE` and the `useCallback` function in a custom hook, and you can use it in multiple places.

Ex:

```
export default () => {

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState('value here')
  const myLittleFunction = useCallback((image: string | undefined) => {
    mySetState(image)
  }, [
    mySetState,
  ])

  return {
    myState,
    setMyState,
    myLittleFunction,
  }

}
```

Comment: Thx @Mina it's interesting, but I use this function to retrieve an image from a child component (I edited my question, sorry)

Comment: Never mind, but where is the `myLittleFunction` here `<MyChildComponent
  setImage={setPickerResponse}
  />`, Also what is the issue you face when using this approach, if you use this function to retrieve an image from a child component?

Comment: myLittleFunction is in the parent component and I have no particular issue with setImage={setPickerResponse} , I can do the same, with the hook pass the function to it and instantly retrieve the image?

Comment: I think, there are no issues if you are using the custom hook, you can use the method and the state as if you declare in the component.

Comment: If the stuff isn't clear yet, please provide full example of code, you can use stackoverflow code snippet, or any live editors like codesandbox.

Comment: nope it works perfectly with a custom hook thx ;)